# sql join tales with like

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-like

I have two tables in Postgres, emails which have 10.000.000 rows and spam_email which have 150.000 rows. emails tables is consisted by normal email address like 'example@domain.com', 'example1@domain2.com',etc and the spam tables is consisted with address like '@domain.com','@domain1.com'  etc.

What I want to do is find all the values from emails table that match spam_email table. 
What I did is this code:

```
Insert INTO clean_email(email) 
select distinct email 
from email e 
   join (select email from spam_email) se ON se.email not like s.email
```

But every time I get an error `disk out of space`.

Do you have any other solution to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you consider deleting spam email from **email** table instead of duplicating approx. (10.000.000 - 150.000) rows into another table namely **clean_email**? You won't be losing any data because the deleted data will still be present in the **spam_email** table and **email** table will only store clean emails?

Comment: @zibidyum Thank for you idea. i will give it a try now and i will let you know if its working. Thanks again

Comment: Do I understand correctly you want clean_emails to contain the emails that do not have domains in the spam table?

Comment: @harmic yes. the spam table may contain full address as well like example@example_domain.com

Comment: @zibidyum even the delete statement returns error : No space left on device

Answer (score 1):

If you're running out of disk space then maybe you need more disk space; or maybe you need to configure postgresql to make better use of available resources : https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server .

Having said that, there is no need to join to a subselect and possibly that is using resources for a temporary table or sort which could be avoided.

Your query cannot possibly run as written (there is no table called `s`, so `s.email` can't be right).

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT se.email FROM email e 
  JOIN spam_email se ON e.email NOT LIKE '%' || se.email;
```

It will still be a slow query plan; there is no way to do a query like `like '%' || se.email` using an index, so it's going to do a lot of table scanning. Better would be to separate the domain part into another column and put an index on it (or use a function for it and put an index on the function).

Comment: Secifically, your `temp_tablespaces` don't have enough space for the temp files being written for a merge join or sort.

Answer (score 0):

```
Insert INTO clean_email(email) 
select distinct email 
from email e 
   left join spam_email se ON se.email=e.email
where se.email is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to match a record in `èmail` with every record that is `not like` email, which would produce approximately 10000000 x 150000 records, making you run out of space.

I think the query below would be much more closer to what you would like to accomplish, assuming that `spam_email` stores records such as `'@domain1.com'`.

```
insert into clear_email(email)
select distinct
  e.email
from email e
inner join spam_email se on extract_domain_from_mail(e.email) = se.email
```